# How can I inform mypy that a Set[re.Match] does not contain None?

Tags: python, mypy

I have code:

```py
matched_policies = {...} #some logic to derive a set
return {
        re.search(r"p\d{6}", matched_policy).group(0)
        for matched_policy in matched_policies
}
```

for which mypy throws error:

> error: Item "None" of "Optional[Match[Any]]" has no attribute "group"

I know that there will be no None values in this set and I know from my previous question [Can I inform mypy that an expression will not return an Optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471392/can-i-inform-mypy-that-an-expression-will-not-return-an-optional) that its possible to inform mypy that a value will not be None by using an assert, but how do I do that for a set?

I tried changing my code to

```py
assert None not in matched_policies
return {
    re.search(r_search, matched_policy).group(0)
    for matched_policy in matched_policies
}
```

but that made no difference, I still get the same error. I can get around it by using a loop:

```py
prefixes = set()
for matched_policy in matched_policies:
    search_result = re.search(r_search, matched_policy)
    assert search_result is not None
    prefixes.add(search_result.group(0))
return prefixes
```

but that feels very inelegant so I don't want to do it, I would much rather use a set comprehension.

How can I assert that all elements in a set are not None in a way that satisfies mypy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not with what's in your set, but that `re.search` returns `Optional[Match[Any]]`.

If you have at least Python 3.8, you can use an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (aka walrus operator) inside your comprehension:

```
    matched_policies = {}
    return {
        match.group(0)
        for matched_policy in matched_policies
        if (match := re.search(r"p\d{6}", matched_policy)) is not None
    }
```

Mypy will find no issues there.

Comment: oh, this is great. This actually solves the performance issue I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: nice. thank you very much (yes, we are using python 3.8)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish what you want by using an if-clause in a list comprehension. Like below:

```
return {
        re.search(r"p\d{6}", matched_policy).group(0)
        for matched_policy in matched_policies if re.search(r_search, matched_policy) is not None
}
```

However, this comes at a performance cost because now you will compute the re.search two times. Once for the if condition and once for the actual operation.

If performance is not a concern, you can do that, but I would prefer the for loop you wrote.