# Why isn't `all` builtin defined as TypeGuard?

Tags: python, python-typing

Let's say I have the following (common, there are similar SO questions, e.g. about [filtering `set[re.Match | None]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079873/how-can-i-inform-mypy-that-a-setre-match-does-not-contain-none)):

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence

def foo(items: Sequence[str | None]) -> list[str]:
    if all(items):
        return [item + '!' for item in items]  # E: Unsupported left operand type for + ("None")  [operator]
    raise ValueError
```

This fails, claiming that `None + str` is an invalid operation.

This is obvious, given that in [`builtins.py` of typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/5ebf892d0710a6e87925b8d138dfa597e7bb11cc/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1201) we currently have a simple definition:

```py
def all(__iterable: Iterable[object]) -> bool: ...
```

However, let's pretend that we are typeshed authors (or are using custom typeshed with `mypy`) and tweak the definition:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import TypeGuard, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')
def all(__iterable: Iterable[_T | None]) -> TypeGuard[Iterable[_T]]: ...
```

Now the code above typechecks properly! Here's the [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict%2Cwarn-unreachable&gist=8a0e35fe0ba5ff8b1c1fab0e03fb301d) with this solution.

Usually we (moreover, I did it myself) answer that it's too much of magic for type checker to support such kind of inference - but that seems to be wrong? It's just about definition of builtin function.

What are the drawbacks of such definition? I understand that it is probably "more than at is" (I mean that `all` is like a one-size-fits-all solution, nobody thinks about it as about such type guard, and `None` is only one example of filtered out values) - but hey, it (I guess) doesn't harm, and simplifies some code pieces greatly.

Moreover, it allows for simple testing of several variables as once:

```py
def foo(a: str | None, b: str | None) -> str:
    together = [a, b]
    if all(together):
        a, b = together
        return a + b
    raise ValueError
```

And yes, the above typechecks too with my `all` definition.

To link, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/9749) for this in typeshed repo.

Comment: I looked at the PEP tracker for TypeGuard (https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/5406) and it seems like you're actually OK to start implementing TypeGuard in typeshed. I guess the answer is: nobody's suggested it, so make a PR and see what happens; see if any of `pytype`, `mypy`, `pyright`, and `pyre` have catastrophic failures :)

Comment: Hm, but typeshed [already uses TypeGuard in 13 definitions](https://github.com/python/typeshed/search?q=TypeGuard).

Comment: On second thoughts, since higher kinded types aren’t supported yet, it probably isn’t that useful to turn e.g. a `dict[str | None, object]` into an `Iterable[str]`. Ideally you’d pass in a type bounded to `Iterable[T]`, which would make the type guard more useful.

Comment: Yeah, I finally discovered that too, seems that upcasting with TypeGuard is a popular problem. If you post it as answer, I'll happily accept it (I already commented it on github issue).